# File.GetCreationTime returns Win32 Error 18 - There are no more files

Tags: c#

**Observations**

I have an application which I have been told was running for several years with no issues, but has recently started crashing with a strange error. The code itself is fairly simple:

```
private void fileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //Make sure it's not a folder that was modified
    if (!Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
    {
        var creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(e.FullPath);

        // Rest of the code here...
```

However, the call to `GetCreationTime`, occasionally raises an exception, producing the following call stack:

```
System.IO.IOException: There are no more files.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.GetCreationTimeUtc(String path)
   at MyClass.fileSystemWatcher_Changed(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) 
   at ...
```

Now, I have scrubbed the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.100).aspx) on `GetCreationTime` as well as examined the code closely using ILSpy, and have reached the following conclusions:

The `System.IO.File.GetCreationTime` method is an advanced wrapper to the equivalent set of Win API calls, including `GetFileAttributesEx` and `FindFirstFile`. I do not believe any of these calls *should* be returning error 18. In fact, the .NET implementation has a specific set of hard-coded errors it is expecting (2, 3, and 21), and in most cases will just eat the exception and return `DateTime.MinValue` instead.

**Questions**

What could be causing this exception, and what are the the best corrective actions to the code to avoid or prevent it? (Right now, I have added `try catch` around the block to just log the event and ignore.)

Could this be a Windows OS issue (similar to this old [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbview/841524))?

Comment: How often are files added and removed from the folder that is being watched?

Comment: You are calling **File**.GetCreationTime on a Directory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It looks like a file to me. It's checking to make sure it *isn't* a directory. *!*Directory.Exists

Comment: @vcsjones `!Directory.Exists` doesn't mean it is a file. It just means that no such directory exist.

Comment: @vcsjones In this case the OP should use `File.Exists`.

Comment: My crystal ball says that this is anti-malware hiding the file.  You can't see it until it is done scanning the file.

Comment: @HansPassant, your crystal ball might explain the random and intermittent nature of the problem. Regarding the other comments, I agree I should check if File exists rather than Directory not exists, but either way, `GetFileCreationTime` should not generate a Win32 Exception - even when passing in a directory or non-existant file

Comment: Hmya, trouble is that it hides the file *while* your program is searching for it.  I've seen several of these kind of "file temporarily disappears" questions in the past few months, smells like an AV vendor has updated their engine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking whether a path is *not* a directory. A `false` response doesn't mean that the path points to a file, it can also mean that there is nothing with this name.

Use `File.Exists` instead:

```
if (FileExists(e.FullPath))
{
    var creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(e.FullPath);
```

Comment: However, calling `File.GetCreationTime` on a directory path or on a non-existent file should not raise an exception. See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QTIBzd